# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)^n+\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)^n}{x^n},n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

If we use the following
$$a^n-b^n=\left(a-b\right)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\right)=u\times t$$

$$u=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}-x+\sqrt{x^2-1}=2\sqrt{x^2-1}=2x\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}$$

Now, the limit is
$$2\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}\times t}{x^n}$$

What to do next, if this is a good approach?

Comment: Can't you just divide the $x^n$ in the denominator into the top and you get two terms equal to one and the rest go to zero.  So seems the limit should be equal to two.

Comment: Try $x=\cosh(t)$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza I was about to write that - and then write cosh and sinh in terms of exponential functions.

Comment: @MarkBennet, and then use definition of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$

Comment: You made an error in expanding because you have + and you use -. I believe that using the proper expansion will greatly simplify the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this properties: $$\frac{a^n}{b^n}=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n\tag{1}$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[f(x)\pm g(x)\right]=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\pm \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)\tag{2}$$

> if and only if the limit of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exists

---

Therefore:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}{x^n}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}\right)^n+\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}\right)^n\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{x(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}})}{x}\right]^n+\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{x(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x}\right]^n\\&=\underbrace{\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)^n}_{2^n}+\underbrace{\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)^n}_{0}\\&=2^n\end{align}$$

Comment: The statement "$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[f(x)\pm g(x)\right]=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\pm \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$
**if and only if** the limit of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exists" is not true. Consider $f(x) = \cos(x)$ and $g(x) = -\cos(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Correction to your answer: $$2\sqrt{x^2-1}=2x\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Your approach is going to have trouble because $t$ is a fairly complicated mess.

Note:

$$\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x} = 1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}\to 2\text{ as } x\to +\infty$$

and

$$\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}= 1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}\to 0\text{ as }x\to+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a= x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$, then we have $x-\sqrt{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{a}$ and $a+ \frac{1}{a}= 2x$. Next, we can write $$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}{x^n}
=\lim\limits_{a\to+\infty}\frac{a^n+\frac{1}{a^n}}{\frac{1}{2^n}(a+\frac{1}{a})^n}=\lim\limits_{a\to+\infty}\frac{a^n}{\frac{1}{2^n}(a)^n}= 2^{n}$$

Comment: After the substitution you have $a\rightarrow +\infty$ but $a=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}{x^n}
$$
$$= \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}(1+\sqrt{1-x^{-2}})^n+ \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}(1-\sqrt{1-x^{-2}})^n = 2^n + 0 = 2^n$$